# How to change dataframe row index to datetime.date while reading from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

`df.index[0]` I want to be `datetime.date(2006, 8, 27)`.

While reading from file, `df = pd.read_csv(filePath,index_col="Date")`, `df.index[0]` appears as string `'2006-08-27'`.

I tried:

```
dateparser = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
df = pd.read_csv(filePath,parse_dates=["Date"], date_parser=dateparser,index_col="Date")
```

Now, `df.index[0]` appears as `Timestamp('2006-08-27 00:00:00')`.

How to make `df.index[0]` as `datetime.date(2006, 8, 27)`?

used sample csv:

```
Date,Symbol,Series,Prev Close,Open,High,Low,Last,Close,VWAP,Volume,Turnover,Trades,Deliverable Volume,%Deliverble
2006-08-27,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2006-08-28,ATFC,EQ,365.0,521.0,569.0,502.0,553.0,554.25,552.0,15166163,837176013020000.0,,3777529,0.24910000000000002
2006-08-29,ATFC,EQ,554.25,555.0,563.9,535.55,536.1,539.3,547.59,3929113,215153038915000.0,,727534,0.1852
2006-08-30,ATFC,EQ,539.3,537.0,542.9,521.5,529.0,528.1,529.55,2034983,107762957620000.0,,345064,0.1696
2006-08-31,ATFC,EQ,528.1,525.0,544.0,515.0,539.35,538.45,532.89,1670990,89044643830000.0,,286440,0.1714
2006-09-01,ATFC,EQ,538.45,539.0,549.0,535.1,541.35,541.85,542.46,1176195,63803856150000.0,,213842,0.1818
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to get any oneliner.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filePath)   # load dataframe
df["Date"]=df["Date"].apply(lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%Y-%m-%d").date()) # convert Date column items to datetime.date
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True) # set Date as row index
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a lambda function there is already a function to change the data to datetime [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

so you could do something like this :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filePath,index_col="Date")

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] ,format = '%Y-%m-%d')

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.date())

print(type(df['Date'][0]))
```

Output

`<class 'datetime.date'>`

There's also a format argument in the function in order to match your data
[Format](https://strftime.org/)

I think your format is  `format = '%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: `df.index[0]` appeared as `0` of class `int` as row index is not changed to "Date".

Comment: I forgot to add the argument `index_col="Date"` which makes the date the index column which causes the integer output. , Also I tried a mapping which is basically what you did with the parser but in a different way and it worked on my local machine

Comment: I edited the original answer with the latest thing I tried along with the output

Answer (score 1):

As per [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can also specify the `parse_dates = True` and the `infer_datetime_format = True` arguments to have pandas attempt to parse dates from the index, which you have set to date.
As in:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filePath,index_col="Date",parse_dates=True,infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: `df.index[0]` appeared as `Timestamp('2006-08-27 00:00:00')`